# JFrame not showing at all

Tags: java, macos, swing, jframe

I am very aware that this question has popped up a lot, I've searched and I couldn't find the solution to this, I'm trying to make a `JFrame` to pop up and show a button which then plays some music for 4 seconds, but the program won't even show the `JFrame`

**This is the main class:**

```
package practs;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

    private static JButton button;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Sound s = new Sound("/Users/seb/Documents/workspace(NormalJava)/practs/res/backgroundMusic.wav");

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Sound Meister");
        f.setFocusable(true);
        f.setSize(300,300);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        button = new JButton("Press to view 4 secs of music");
        f.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

                        s.play();
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(4000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        s.stop();
                    }
                }
                );
        f.setVisible(true);


    }
}
```

**The Sound class if needed:**

```
package practs;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

public class Sound {
    private Clip clip;
    public Sound(String fileName) {
        // specify the sound to play
        // (assuming the sound can be played by the audio system)
        // from a wave File
        try {
            File file = new File(fileName);
            if (file.exists()) {
                AudioInputStream sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
             // load the sound into memory (a Clip)
                clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                clip.open(sound);
            }
            else {
                throw new RuntimeException("Sound: file not found: " + fileName);
            }
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Sound: Malformed URL: " + e);
        }
        catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Sound: Unsupported Audio File: " + e);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Sound: Input/Output Error: " + e);
        }
        catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Sound: Line Unavailable Exception Error: " + e);
        }

    // play, stop, loop the sound clip
    }
    public void play(){
        clip.setFramePosition(0);  // Must always rewind!
        clip.start();
    }
    public void loop(){
        clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
    }
    public void stop(){
        clip.stop();
    }
}
```

I'd be very glad if anyone could solve this problem for me.

Comment: This `Thread.sleep(4000);` is a bad start. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

Comment: @MadProgrammer even after I remove the Thread.sleep (including the try & catch obviously) and just leave the s.play(); the JFrame still does not show itself

Comment: Without the `Sound` class, it runs just fine for me.  I'm using Java 8, what are you using...?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm using Java 8 too, perhaps I need to restart Eclipse... I'll look at the answers, restarting it doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much screwing around, this would seem to be one of those situation where not building the UI within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread is causing some kind of deadlock...

Basically, I took you `main` code block, wrapped in an `EventQueue.invokeLater` and it worked fine...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            Sound s = new Sound("/Users/swhitehead/Downloads/checked.wav");

            JFrame f = new JFrame("Sound Meister");
            f.setFocusable(true);
            f.setSize(300, 300);
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            button = new JButton("Press to view 4 secs of music");
            f.add(button);
            button.addActionListener(
                    new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                            s.play();
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(4000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            s.stop();
                        }
                    }
            );
            f.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

}
```

You should ALWAYS start you UI within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details...

Next, that `Thread.sleep` is going to cause some issues, see [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

Comment: That worked! Thanks for helping :) I'm not at all familiar with runnable so that's why I shy away from it, thanks a lot again :)

Comment: Yeah, that was a weird one, I wouldn't have expected this behaviour, but when in doubt, invoke later :P

Answer (score 3):

As is, your code doesn't compile.  `Sounds s` should be `final` since you reference it in your anonymous `ActionListener` class.

```
final Sound s =
```

Fixing that, the frame should show.  If it still doesn't, then perhaps `new Sound()` is throwing an exception.  Be sure you are using a development environment where you can see console output.

Comment: Funny enough, under java 8 I've found final doesn't seem to be required, or at least it compiles, but without further evidence, this is a good reasoning

Comment: Unfortunately, final doesn't work. but I commented sound s = new Sound(); and the s.play in the ActionListener, and the button does in fact show up, but I'm certain that the file I gave it is working, and is found by the program.